# When $n$ is even, $SO_{n}\times \mathbb{Z_{2}}$ is not isomorphic to $O_{n}$.

Tags: group-theory

I have no idea how to proceed here other than assuming the groups are isomorphic and deriving a contradiction. I understand the proof that $SO_{n} \times \mathbb{Z_{2}}$ is isomorphic to $O_{n}$ when $n$ is odd. Any hints on where to start?

Comment: Your title and second sentence seem to contradict each other.

Comment: Sorry, i meant when $n$ is odd.

Comment: Hint:  When $n$ is even, the center of $SO_n\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$.  But, when $n$ is even, the center of $O(n)$ is $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: @Jason DeVito Thank you. As simple as the concept of centre is, we haven't learned it yet and I prefer not to assume it. Should I perhaps explore the images of $I$ and $-I$ under the isomorphism?

Comment: If you haven't learned about the center yet, you can count the number of elements in each if the two groups which commute with all the rest.

Comment: @Mariano Suarez-Alvarez Thank you. The commuting elements of $O_{n}$ are $I$ and $-I$, and those of $SO_{n}\times\mathbb{Z_{2}}$ are $(I,0)$, $(I,1)$, $(-I,0)$, and $(-I,1)$. This makes sense in the context of Jason DeVito's comments as well. Thank you both. I will provide the details in my own answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt. Suppose $\phi : O_{n}\rightarrow SO_{n}\times \mathbb{Z_{2}}$ is an isomorphism, where $n$ is even. Because $n$ is even, we have four elements of $SO_{n}\times \mathbb{Z_{2}}$ which commute with every element of itself, namely $(\pm I,0),(\pm I,1)$. Since $\phi$ is an isomorphism, we have $$\phi(I)=(I,0),\space \phi(A)=(I,1),\space \phi(B)=(-I,0)$$where $A$ and $B$ are unique matrices in $O_{n}$. Let $M\in O_n$ and let $\phi(M)=(M',k)$, $k\in \mathbb{Z_2}$, be its image in $SO_n\times \mathbb{Z_2}$. It follows that$$\phi(AM)=\phi(A)\phi(M)=(I,1)(M,k)=(M,k)(I,1)=\phi(M)\phi(A)= \phi(MA)$$ which implies $AM=MA$. Similarly, $\phi(BM)=\phi(MB)$ implies $BM=MB$. Thus we have at least 3 unique elements (in fact, there is one more, but who needs it), $I,A$, and $B$ in $O_n$ which commute with every other element in $O_n$. This is impossible because  $O_n$  only has 2 commutative elements $I$ and $-I$.

Comment: I think I would  clarify why $A$ and $B$ commute with everything.  You've shown the commute with each other, but why do they commute with everything?  In addition, once you know $A$ and $B$ commute with everything, you are already done:  This implies that $\{A,B\} = \{I, -I\}$.  But $\phi(A)$ and $\phi(B)$ are both not $\phi(I)$, contradicting the fact that $\phi$ is a function.

Comment: Well put. I made corrections based on your suggestion, but used the fact that isomorphisms preserve commutativity. What do you think now?

Comment: Looks much better.

Comment: Thanks once again for your help.